# How can we add comments in flex/bison source code?

Tags: comments, bison, flex-lexer

Like in other languages, we can add comments using either //, /*---*/, #, % etc. So similarly if I want to add comments in flex/bison source code for better understanding of code. Can I do the same? If yes then how?
Whenever I tried to search about same on the internet, answers usually come for defining comment in flex/bison and not about how to add comments in flex/bison source code.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison Just look up the syntax of flex/bison.

Comment: If we don't have any solution then I am thinking about workaround if we add a rule/grammar which does nothing and use c action section to add comments, it can work

Comment: You can just use `/* */`.

Comment: Even the Wikipedia link shows comments-i don't really see the issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**(F)lex:** Indent the comment, and use a comment style appropriate to the generated code. (`/*...*/` is recommended.) You must indent every line of the comment. Indented text is copied verbatim to the generated file, but a comment is a comment.

**Yacc/Bison:** Use `/* ... */` anywhere in the grammar. In bison, but possibly not other yacc derivatives, you can also use `//` comments.